# Get the wallpaper file name for the currently displayed wallpaper in a theme in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, function, windows-7, jna, wallpaper

I am using JNA to call system libraries on Windows 7 and need a way to get the current wallpaper file name that is being displayed from a theme where it randomly changes the wallpaper at a set interval.

I have used the SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER system call in user32 using SystemParametersInfo but it returns the following path for each and every wallpaper no matter which is selected:

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg
```

but the original wallpaper are in say C:\wallpapers

Is there any way to get the original wallpaper file name?  This transcoded wallpaper file name is useless for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a short script  [available here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-background-file-location-right-click-menu-windows-7/) which does what you want it to do.

The file name of the source for the current wallpaper is stored in a registry variable.